# Re-direct YouTube to 127.0.0.1 [locally hosted webpage] using HOSTS file?

Tags: html, dns, hosts

I am hosting a webpage locally, at `127.0.0.1`. Using the **hosts** file on **Windows 10**, I successfully re-directed certain domains to my local webpage. For example:

```
127.0.0.1 9gag.com
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
```

Visiting those domains through any web-browser successfully re-directs to the local webpage.

---

**However**... This method is not working for other domains, such as:

```
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

Instead of rendering my hosted webpage, web-browsers return:

```
This site can’t be reached
www.youtube.com refused to connect.

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

for both Facebook and YouTube.

---

Is it possible to redirect these domains using the **hosts** file? And if not, is there another simple method of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), you will have to run your local website on port 443, over https (there will also be a browser warning because of invalid certificate...)

Comment: Thank you, i will try that. Hvala! :)